# Pebble C, Getting Char at Specified Position

Tags: c, char, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

It's been a while since I last programmed using C, but it seems I'm confused with pointers and strings. I'm writing a Pebble watch face and I need to separate the digits for the minutes into the ones digit and the tens digit and put them into their respective containers.

So if the minutes is 25, I need to separate 2 and 5 and put them into two separate `char` variable.

The code I wrote is

```
static void update_time() {
  time_t temp = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);

  static char d_minute[] = "00";      

  if (clock_is_24h_style() == true)  {
    strftime(d_minute, sizeof("00"), "%M", tick_time);    
  } else {    
    strftime(d_minute, sizeof("00"), "%M", tick_time);    
  }     

  text_layer_set_text(s_m_one_layer, &d_minute[1]);  // ones' place for 2[5]
  text_layer_set_text(s_m_ten_layer, &d_minute[0]);  // tens' place for [2]5

}
```

The `&d_minute[1]` returns 5 correctly. However, `&d_minute[0]` returns the whole string, 25. What am I missing here? How can I access the first character in a `char[]`?

As an interim solution, what I did was to declare a 2-character `char` and `strncpy` `&d_minute[0]` into it, forcing it to copy just the first character.

```
 static char min_ten[] = "  ";
 .....
 strncpy(min_ten, &d_minute[0], 1);
 ....
 text_layer_set_text(s_m_ten_layer, min_ten);
```

which I think is code smell. How do I get the tens' value in C?

Comment: if I remove the &, i.e. `text_layer_set_text(s_m_ten_layer, d_minute[0]);`, the compiler returns the `passing argument 2 of 'text_layer_set_text' makes pointer from integer without a cast` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally your `d_minute` string is stored like this:

```
d_minute = {'2', '5', '\0'}
```

the last character `\0` terminates the string, by this way `text_layer_set_text` knows that the string has ended.

When you call

```
text_layer_set_text(&d_minute[0],...)
```

then this is the equivalent of calling it like this

```
text_layer_set_text(d_minute,...)
```

You need to tell the function where the string you want to print ends, so your workaround is actually the right way to do it.

Comment: Okay thanks! The  'text_layer_set_text' is an SDK function so I can't tinker it.

Comment: @Devmonster yes and the way you did it looks fine anyways